# magento custom payment gateway for National Bank Greece

Tags: php, magento, payment-gateway, payment

I am using [KBariotis](https://github.com/kbariotis/KBariotis_NBP) module to integrate magento with National Bank of Greece.
I tried everything but it's not working.

At first, it would not recognise the module.
So I changed `protected $_formBlockType = 'nbp/form_nbp';` on /model/standard.php to
`protected $_formBlockType = 'nbp/form_NBP';`

Now it recognises it as a valid payment option.
But on checkout, it redirects me to /checkout/onepage/failure

edit:

In the code model/NBP.php I see that getRedirectUrl() returns false and not what it should. Here is the code

```
    <?php
class KBariotis_NBP_Model_NBP extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{

private $proxyPayEndPoint = null;
private $merchantID = null;
private $merchantSecret = null;
private $newOrderStatus = null;
private $pageSetId = null;
private $enable3dSecure = null;


protected function _Construct()
{
    $this->merchantID       = Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/nbp/merchant_id');
    $this->proxyPayEndPoint = Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/nbp/proxy_pay_endpoint');
    $this->merchantSecret   = Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/nbp/merchant_confirmation_pwd');
    $this->pageSetId        = Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/nbp/page_set_id');
    $this->newOrderStatus   = Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/nbp/order_status');
    $this->enable3dSecure   = Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/nbp/enable_3d_secure');
}

public function getRedirectUrl()
{

    $order   = new Mage_Sales_Model_Order();
    $orderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')
                   ->getLastRealOrderId();
    $order->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
    $orderTotal = $order->getBaseGrandTotal();
    $successUrl = Mage::getUrl('nbp/payment/success/');

    $request = $this->createXMLRequestPreTransaction($orderId, $orderTotal, $successUrl);

    if ($response = $this->makeRequest($request))
        return $response->HpsTxn->hps_url . '?HPS_SessionID=' . $response->HpsTxn->session_id;
    else
        return false;
}

private function createXMLRequestPreTransaction($orderId, $orderTotal, $successUrl)
{
    $request = new SimpleXMLElement("<Request></Request>");
    $request->addAttribute("version", "2");

    $auth = $request->addChild("Authentication");
    $auth->addChild("password", $this->merchantSecret);
    $auth->addChild("client", $this->merchantID);

    $transaction = $request->addChild("Transaction");
    $txnDetails  = $transaction->addChild("TxnDetails");
    $txnDetails
        ->addChild("merchantreference", $orderId);

    if ($this->enable3dSecure) {
        $threeDSecure = $txnDetails->addChild("ThreeDSecure");
        $browser      = $threeDSecure->addChild("Browser");

        $browser->addChild("device_category", 0);
        $browser->addChild("accept_headers", "*/*");
        $browser->addChild("user_agent", "IE/6.0");

        $threeDSecure->addChild("purchase_datetime", date('Ymd H:i:s'));
        $threeDSecure->addChild("purchase_desc", $orderId);
        $threeDSecure->addChild("verify", "yes");

    }

    $txnDetails
        ->addChild("amount", $orderTotal)
        ->addAttribute("currency", "EUR");
    $txnDetails
        ->addChild("capturemethod", "ecomm");

    $hpsTxn = $transaction->addChild("HpsTxn");
    $hpsTxn
        ->addChild("method", "setup_full");
    $hpsTxn
        ->addChild("page_set_id", $this->pageSetId);
    $hpsTxn
        ->addChild("return_url", $successUrl);
    $hpsTxn
        ->addChild("expiry_url", Mage::getUrl(''));

    $cardTxn = $transaction->addChild('CardTxn');
    $cardTxn
        ->addChild("method", "auth");

    return $request;
}

public function queryRefTransaction($ref)
{

    $request = $this->createXMLRequestPostTransaction($ref);

    if ($response = $this->makeRequest($request))
        return $response->merchantreference;

    return false;

}

private function createXMLRequestPostTransaction($ref)
{

    $request = new SimpleXMLElement("<Request></Request>");
    $request->addAttribute("version", "2");

    $auth = $request->addChild("Authentication");
    $auth->addChild("password", $this->merchantSecret);
    $auth->addChild("client", $this->merchantID);

    $transaction = $request->addChild("Transaction");
    $historicTxn = $transaction->addChild("HistoricTxn");
    $historicTxn
        ->addChild("method", "query");
    $historicTxn
        ->addChild("reference", $ref);

    return $request;
}

private function makeRequest($request)
{
    $client = new Varien_Http_Client($this->proxyPayEndPoint);
    $client->setMethod(Zend_Http_Client::POST);
    $client->setRawData($request->asXML());

    $response = $client->request();
    if (!$response->isSuccessful())
        throw new Mage_Payment_Exception('Could not communicate to payment server');        

    $responseBody = $response->getBody();

    $response = simplexml_load_string($responseBody);

    $status = intval($response->status);

    if ($status != 1 && $status != 7)
        Mage::log('Error from the Bank : ' . $responseBody);

    if ($status == 7)
        Mage::log('Bank refused the payment : ' . $responseBody);

    if ($status == 1)
        return $response;

    return false;
}

public function getNewOrderStatus()
{
    return $this->newOrderStatus;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although, it's been 4 months since you posted this question I am answering.

1. Check that your proxyPayEndPoint is the correct valid url.
2. The page Set ID should be filled. (An id of an existed page that you you are using for validation).
3. In case you have 3DSecure enabled, you should have the elements correctly filled.

`$browser->addChild("device_category", 0);`

`$headers = apache_request_headers();
 $browser->addChild("accept_headers", ($headers['Accept']?(string)$headers['Accept']:"*/*"));
 $browser->addChild("user_agent", (string)$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);`

You could print the xml request `(your_website_url/nbp/payment/redirect/)` and see the response and what is probably missing from your structure.